# Python subsetting and slicing with [index,:] format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've seen python DataFrames sometimes subsetted using the [index,:] notation when sometimes using [index] would suffice.

Using a simple toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,5,10,15,20,50,88]})
idx = [2,4,6]
```

We can call the iloc method using either of these:

```
df.iloc[idx,:]
df.iloc[idx]
```

To get results:

```
    a
2  10
4  20
6  88
```

Are there any differences between the call methods? Should I prefer the use of one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `df.iloc[idx,:]` the colon is slicing over the columns. In python when you use [:] you slice over all the options. As example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,5,10,15,20,50,88], 'b':[1,5,10,15,20,50,88]})
idx = [2,4,6]
```

#### Without columns slicing:

```
df.iloc[idx]
```

output:

```
    a   b
2   10  10
4   20  20
6   88  88
```

#### With columns slicing:

```
df.iloc[idx,:1]
```

output:

```
    a
2   10
4   20
6   88
```

In this case the question is if you want to explicitly slice over all the columns. In my modest opinion I think it will be clear as the standar form `df.iloc[idx]`.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Mainly they're same.

> Axes left out of the specification are assumed to be :. (e.g.
>   p.loc['a'] is equiv to p.loc['a', :, :])
>
> [Different Choices for Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing)

Comment: Thank you for your reply